# Measurability of a random function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $(U_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ is a stochastic process such that for every $\{t_1,t_2,\dots ,t_n\}\subset[0,1]$, $$U_{t_1},U_{t_2},\dots ,U_{t_n}\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}\left(\frac12\right).$$ Let $$A=\left\{\omega : U_t(\omega) \text{ is a Lebesgue measurable function of $t$}\right\}.$$ Is $A$ measurable in the product space, and if so, what is $P(A)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Intuitively, it should not be  measurable. The only sets measurable in the product sigma algebra are those which depend on the function's value at only countably many points. You can't tell whether a function is Lebesgue measurable by inspecting it at countably many points.